# Can I pass redux action creators in a context object?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-context

Currently, I'm building a survey builder. I want to start the project with testability in mind. I'm striving for a clear separation of Container and View components. One idea I've had was to pass a lot of the redux action creators as part of a context object down a component tree. Turns out, this isn't particularly easy to test. Also, it might be a very bad design, but I would love to have some input on this. Is this a clear anti-pattern?

```
import {
    getSurvey,
    addAnswer,
    removeAnswer,
    addQuestionNotification,
    updateAnswer,
    removeQuestionNotification,
} from "actions";

const Survey: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {


    const goToNextPage = () => {...};

    const goToPrevPage = () => {...};

    const validateQuestion = () => {...}

    const validateModule = () => {...};

    const validatePage = (...) => {...};

    const validateFullSurvey = (...) => {};

    return (
        <div>
            <SurveyContext.Provider
                value={{
                    addAnswer: props.addAnswer,
                    removeAnswer: props.removeAnswer,
                    updateAnswer: props.updateAnswer,
                    answerList: props.answerList,
                    addQuestionNotification: props.addQuestionNotification,
                    removeQuestionNotification:
                        props.removeQuestionNotification,
                    surveyNotifications: props.surveyNotifications,
                    validateFullSurvey: validateFullSurvey,
                    validatePage: validatePage,
                    validateModule: validatePage,
                    validateQuestion: validateQuestion,
                }}
            >
                {...more components...}
            </SurveyContext.Provider>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: This is a poor design, React isn't [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern, you don't need this separation.

Comment: What you should do, is read about recommended design choices in redux docs.